# python pandas filtering dataframe get unexpected one extra row

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading some CSV files with:

```
apds = pandas.read_csv( out + '.apds.txt', sep='\t' )
cnds = pandas.read_csv( out + '.cnds.txt', sep='\t' )
gnds = pandas.read_csv( out + '.genotype.txt', sep='\t' )
```

The idea is to reduce the 3 DataFrame having the same index, but the file loaded to gnds it has not the index, I must add it as:

```
names = cnds.ix[ gnds.Index ][ 'ProbeSetName' ]
names = names.reset_index()[ 'ProbeSetName' ]
gnds[ 'ProbeSetName' ] = names
```

Now the 3 DataFames have a column called "ProbeSetName" I will use as index:

```
gnds = gnds.set_index( 'ProbeSetName' )
cnds = cnds.set_index( 'ProbeSetName' )
apds = apds.set_index( 'ProbeSetName' )
```

So, the idea is to create a pandas' Serie with the common elements of "ProbeSetName" of each DataFrame:

```
im = list( set.intersection( set( gnds.index ), set( cnds.index ), set( apds.index ) ) )
s = pandas.Series( im )
```

With that, "s" has the common elements of the 3 DataFrames. I can filter the DataFrames with:

```
apds_f = apds.ix[ s ]
cnds_f = cnds.ix[ s ]
gnds_f = gnds.ix[ s ]
```

And It works perfectly but when I do:

```
print len( apds_f ), len( cnds_f ), len( gnds_f )
```

I got:

```
697077 697077 697078
```

...and I don't know why!?

Comment: Are there multiple rows with the same index?  Try `g = pd.value_counts(gnds_f.index); print g[g > 1]`.

Comment: Ok... that is! I have two elements of "S-4IYCH".
Result of your code: S-4IYCH    2

Comment: May I can ask how to remove the duplicated row?
I've tried to group it selecting the first instance "gnds_f = gnds_f.groupby( gnds_f.index ).first()" but I got an error: "AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length"